# Enhancing Call Status Notifications in a Progressive Web App with Twilio Integration

Tags: push-notification, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, twilio-click-to-call

I am working on a Progressive Web App and developing a notification feature. I want to create a persistent notification that does not hide or disappear when clicked. Additionally, I don't want the "delete notification" button to be shown on the swipe-left gesture for Android devices.

Furthermore, if a user clicks on the "clear all notifications" button on Android, the persistent notification that I created should not be cleared. Instead, only the other notifications should be cleared, leaving the persistent one unaffected.

I have been trying to find a solution for preserving a persistent notification without much success. Essentially, I aim to handle calling features in my Progressive Web App using Twilio. When a user is called on a particular number, my PWA should send notifications indicating the call status. For instance, when the call is ringing, a notification is sent; if the user attempts to pick up the call, the notification status changes to 'ongoing,' and if the call ends or is disconnected, a notification should indicate 'call ended' and 'disconnected.'

I want to manage the calling status through push notifications, similar to how WhatsApp displays notification statuses during calls. This is what I want to implement in my Progressive Web App.

Furthermore, I'd like the notifications to persist even after clicking on them. Additionally, if the user clicks on the 'clear all' button, the notifications should not be cleared; they should only be cleared when the user ends or disconnects the call.

Technology Stack:- Javascript,html,css and nodejs

Could someone assist me in developing this functionality using service workers? I appreciate any guidance or help in achieving this.